# Interrupt a sleeping Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a way to Interupt a sleeping thread?  If I have code similar to this.

```
while(true){
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastExecuteTime).TotalHours > 1){
        DoWork();
        _lastExecuteTime = DateTime.Now();
        continue; 
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000) //Sleep 10 seconds
    if(somethingIndicatingQuit){
        break;
    }

}
```

I'm wanting to execute DoWork() every hour. So, I'd like to sleep a little longer then 10 seconds. Say check every 10 minutes or so.  However, if set my sleep to 10 minutes, and I want to kill this background task, I have to wait for the sleep to resume.

My actual code is using a Threading.ManualResetEvent to shut down the background work, but my issue is with the ThreadSleep code. I can post more code if necessary.

OK, I'm going to add a bit more complete code here as I think it will answer some of the questions.

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private readonly ManualResetEvent _pauseEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
private Thread _backGroundWorkerThread;

//This starts our work
public void Start() {
    _backGroundWorkerThread = new Thread(ExecuteWorker) {IsBackground = true, Name = WorkerName + "_Thread"};
    _shutdownEvent.Reset();
    _backGroundWorkerThread.Start();
}
internal void Stop() {
    //Signal the shutdown event
    _shutdownEvent.Set();

    //Make sure to resume any paused threads
    _pauseEvent.Set();

    //Wait for the thread to exit
    _backGroundWorkerThread.Join();

}

private void ExecuteWorker() {
    while (true) {
        _pauseEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

        //This kills our process
        if (_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
           break;
        }

        if (!_worker.IsReadyToExecute) {
            //sleep 5 seconds before checking again. If we go any longer we keep our service from shutting down when it needs to.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            continue;
        }
        DoWork();

    }
}
```

My problem is here,

```
_backGroundWorkerThread.Join();
```

This waits for the Thread.Sleep within the ExecuteWorker() that is running in my background thread.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're not using a Timer? You can put that code minus the loop in a method and pass it as the callback for a Timer that executes every n minutes then to stop the task just kill the Timer or set its interval to Infinite.

Comment: I've posted more of the code. The class this code is a child of a parent class that manages an infinite number of these. The parent controls Starting, Stopping, Pausing and Continuing of these child classes and the work they are doing. It's not a simple matter of Start and Stop that needs to be supported.

Comment: what is `_worker` here?

Comment: Just an instance of a class that has scheduling logic. It's method, IsReadyToExecute returns a boolean value.  The _worker is not germane to this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using `Thread.Sleep` use `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne`.

```
while (true) {
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastExecuteTime).TotalHours > 1) {
        DoWork();
        _lastExecuteTime = DateTime.Now();
        continue; 
    }
    if (terminate.WaitOne(10000)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `terminate` is a `ManualResetEvent`<sup>1</sup> that you can `Set` to request termination of the loop.

**Update:**

I just noticed that you said you are already using `ManualResetEvent` to terminate the background work (I am assuming that is in `DoWork`). Is there any reason why you cannot use the same MRE? If that is not possible there certainly should not be an issue using a different one.

**Update 2:**

Yeah, so instead of `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in `ExecuteWorker` do `_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(5000)` instead. It would look like the following.

```
private void ExecuteWorker() {
    while (true) {
        _pauseEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

        //This kills our process
        if (_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
           break;
        }

        if (!_worker.IsReadyToExecute) {
            //sleep 5 seconds before checking again. If we go any longer we keep our service from shutting down when it needs to.
            _shutdownEvent.WaitOne(5000);
            continue;
        }
        DoWork();
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>There is also a `ManualResetEventSlim` class in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Brian. This is exactly what I needed. I ran this solution through all of my test and it worked great! Now calling stop, stops my Worker in it's tracks! Nice to accept an answer from a fellow St. Louis-an!

Comment: @Jeff: Nice, you're the first I've bumped into on here :)

Answer (score 45):

Instead of using `Thread.Sleep`, you can use `Monitor.Wait` with a timeout - and then you can use `Monitor.Pulse` from a different thread to wake it up.

Don't forget you'll need to lock on the monitor before calling either `Wait` or `Pulse`:

```
// In the background thread
lock (monitor)
{
    // If we've already been told to quit, we don't want to sleep!
    if (somethingIndicatingQuit)
    {
        break;
    }
    Monitor.Wait(monitor, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    if (somethingIndicatingQuit)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// To wake it up...
lock (monitor)
{
    somethingIndicatingQuit = true;
    Monitor.Pulse(monitor);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. If it works in my situation, I'll make sure I up-vote and accept your answer. Thanks Jon.

Comment: If Jon Skeet gives you an answer and it *doesn't* work, you're implementing his answer wrong :)

Comment: My example didn't quite match my production code, so while his answer may work for the problem I described, it may not work for my implementation because I didn't represent it correctly.  I've added my full code now, so hopefully that helps answer more questions.

Comment: Also, Jon, you've replaced my endless loop --> while(true) with lock(monitor). Not sure what that does for me.  Also, Monitor.Pulse(); give me an exception of Method 'Pulse' has 1 parameter(s) butis invoked with 0 argument(s).

Comment: @Jeff: No, you'd still have the while true *as well* - heck, there's nothing doing any work there! Have fixed the Wait/Pulse problems - forgot to include an argument.

Comment: Looking at your change, this *absolutely* would work for your scenario. Personally I prefer using monitors over event handles in general, but it's a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm sure your code example will help someone else out.  I've created a WindowsServiceBase dll that this code resides in.  I may post it somewhere and add a link here when I do. My dll uses MEF to load workers implementing an IWorker interface. So I have a Service that runs, but contains not code other than to call my ServiceManager's Stop, Start, Pause, Continue. The Service manager then manages workers that can be added while the service is running. Pretty cool stuff I think. But your code may help before I'm done!

Comment: This is a great answer - solved my issue and it was the best Monitor example I found.  One little request - can you update your answer to clarify what the `monitor` variable is?  Might be obvious to some, but I had to look around a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed great answer - this link below was also very helpful:   http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Thead.Interrupt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) to wake a sleeping thread. It will cause a `ThreadInterruptedException` on the blocked thread, so it's not the most elegant or efficient approach.

You also need to be weary that interrupting a thread in this way is unsafe. It does not provide control over the point at which the thread is aborted, and therefore should not be used without careful consideration as to the consequences. As mentioned in other answers already, it's is far better to use signal based techniques to control when the thread terminates in a controlled manner.

Comment: Unsafe in what way? It throws a `ThreadInteruptedException` on the blocking thread. Maybe you could elaborate? I guess you mean if it's blocking for a reason other than sleep?

Comment: Unsafe because you have no way to know what state the interrupted thread was in. The thread doesn't get interrupted at "safe points" - it gets interrupted wherever it happens to be. This could be a point in time where the state of the application is undefined or incorrect or just plain wrong.

Comment: Fair point, I'll add a note about that for reference. I'm aware there are better alternatives, just didn't want to repeat the same answers.

Comment: `Thread.Interrupt` **is** safe. It is `Thread.Abort` that is not safe. `Interrupt` only causes that BCL waiting calls (like `Join`, `Sleep`, etc.) to return immediately. Unless your code is faulty the `ThreadInterruptException` *should* get injected at safe points and you *do* have full control. Just pay attention to the placement of the blocking calls if you decide to use `Interrupt`. **Again, interrupting and aborting threads are two very different things!**

Comment: It does only Interrupt on next block, but I guess the point is it's not necessarily blocking because of sleep.

Answer (score 2):

why not use a BlockingCollection? I see it as a much more elegant approach than the accepted answer. i also do not think there is much overhead compared to the monitor.

here is how to do it:

initialize a BlockingCollection as a member:

```
BlockingCollection<int> _sleeper = new BlockingCollection<int>();
```

insted of

```
Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

do this

```
int dummy;
_sleeper.TryTake(out dummy, 10000);
```

to wake it up you can use this code

```
_sleeper.Add(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to implement a cancelable `Sleep` method, using the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay)+[`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) combination. The first one must handle an `AggregateException` in case of cancellation, so it is a bit verbose:

```
public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout, cancellationToken).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException aex) when (aex.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Ignore exception
    }
}
```

The second handles an `OperationCanceledException`, so it is nicer:

```
public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout).Wait(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Ignore exception
    }
}
```

The third has no exception to catch, so it is the most succinct:

```
public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout, cancellationToken));
}
```

The [`Task.WaitAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany) accepts a `params Task[]` as argument, so it may be slightly less efficient than the previous options.

More info about cancellation in general: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just wrap your Thread.Sleep portion in a loop so that it loops 60 times then makes the other check? Of course all this does is trades off a simple **if(somethingIndicatingQuit)** versus the DateTIme if check, but assuming maybe you're real code does something more expensive, having a second loop could offer some minor CPU savings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DoWork() every hour, why not calculate the numer of ms required until the next hour is up and wait for that time?  To cancel the sleep, you could either use a waitable synchro class, like the monitor as suggested by @Jon Skeet, or just set a flag in the thread that tells it to exit after the sleep instead of DoWork() and just forget about it - either the thread will kill itself when the time is up or your OS will kill it on app close, whichever comes first.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: It's not the app closing. It's running in a service and has to support Stopping, Pausing and Continue. Currently, if I set the thread to sleep to long, Pausing or Stopping takes too long as it has to wait for the thread to resume from sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Sleep(...)` method to the `SafeSleep(...)` method can be interrupted with `Thread.Interrupt();`:

```
private void SafeSleep(int time)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(time);
    }catch(ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        Log.Debug("Thread sleep interrupted");
    }
}
```

Now the Thread will sleep during the sleep time or before the `Thread.Interrupt()` called. As the exception will be catched, the control will be returned to the Thread normal flow and you can terminate it right.