# Alternate ways to cancel async task

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task

I am trying to find the best way to do this and none of my attempts thus far has worked. Looking for some additional input.

I have a sub that needs to be executed in the background and is something like this

```
Sub Start_Work()

 'Step 1
 Sleep(1000)
 'Step 2
  Sleep(2000)
 'Step3
  Sleep(1000)
 'Step 4

End Sub
```

I call it like so

```
Dim Task1 As Task
Task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Start_Test())
```

All the examples of cancelling task I have seen use a for loop to continuously check for the Cancellation Token but it is a little hard to do in this scenario.

I was thinking of adding a while loop and states but I am unsure how to have the code wait a second or two before going to the next step.

any comments/suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you seen [Interrupt a sleeping Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7448607/1115360)?

Comment: You already have your answer, so why raise a bounty? If you wanted to award the answer, there's a bounty reason for that.

Comment: @cybermonkey Sorry, Im not following? Prior to my bounty there was no answers. After placing the bounty Fredou answered the question with what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use a [manualresetevent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle it

the manualresetevent will allow you to stop it right away and not wait the full sleep time

in this example you will never reach `Console.WriteLine("start wait 3")`

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1

Dim mreWait As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim stopTask As Boolean

Sub Main()
    Dim task1 As task
    task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() start_work())
    Console.WriteLine("waiting")
    Thread.Sleep(1500)
    Console.WriteLine("stop")
    stopTask = True
    mreWait.Set()
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Sub start_work()
    mreWait.Reset()
    Console.WriteLine("start wait 1")
    mreWait.WaitOne(1000)
    If stopTask Then Return

    Console.WriteLine("start wait 2")
    mreWait.WaitOne(1000)
    If stopTask Then Return

    Console.WriteLine("start wait 3")
    mreWait.WaitOne(1000)
    If stopTask Then Return

    Console.WriteLine("stop start_work")
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I will give this a try but I dont think it will solve my problem. One of my sequences needs a 4 second wait, but there is a possibility I might need to cancel out of that entire procedure at the 2second mark. From my understanding this would only check after the wait?

Comment: Nvm, Thank You! This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly. Wish I had found out about it earlier!