# C# How to safely end a thread that saves to file

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, io, persistence

I'm writing a script that auto saves 3 seconds after a change that should be saved and want the 3 second timer to reset if another change happens. I'm also using threading because I don't want the program to stutter if the disk is busy etc.

```
void SaveTimer() 
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000); //wait 3 seconds
    Save(); //writes binary file to disk
}
```

In the above code, a thread begins with "StartTimer". I could kill the thread and start it again every time there is a change, but that could cause issues if the thread was in the middle of saving to disk. I'm not sure how I could safely reset the time waited. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See answer to a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448589/interrupt-a-sleeping-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Well from you question and subsequent comments I can suggest you two options, with some additional "warnings":

1. If your thread loops executing something on each iteration, you can set a volatile boolean flag such that it exits after finishing the current iteration.

Then just set the flag to true when you want the thread to stop and it will stop the next time it checks the condition.

2. If you cannot wait for the iteration to finish and need to stop it immediately, you could go for Thread.Abort, but make absolutely sure that there is no way you can leave open file handles, sockets, locks or anything else like this in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

1) **I recommend that you check to see if this file is being written to already** before you attempt to write to it.

```
void SaveTimer() 
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            yourTimer.Stop();
            Save();
            yourTimer.Start();
        }
    } 
    catch { Thread.Sleep(3000); }
    }
}
```

2. **If possible, it is better to re-factor your code to avoid putting the thread to sleep.**

Comment: The sleep can be interrupted with an interrupt call.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your data you may want to write a large empty file and then hold it open for reading and writing on a dedicated process.

Instead of rewriting the file, simply ferry across to the read/write thread the lines that need changing.

For simplicity, the file should be large enough that it will not need to grow. In this way you've created a rudimentary database.